# Dimension of the Solution Set of a System of Linear Equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

I've been stuck on this question for a while now

Let E be a system of m linear equations and n unknowns. Assume E has *at least* one solution. Then dim(S(E)) is :

a) $\leqslant$ n-m

b) = n-m

c) $\geqslant$ n-m

d) $\leqslant$ m-n

e) = m-n

f) $\geqslant$ m-n

Could you also help me understand the reasoning behind the answer?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! I suppose it is a system of non-homogeneous equations?

Comment: Thank you!
Yes it is

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Let $r$ be the rank of the system, i.e. the rank of its matrix. We know two things:

1. $ \;r\le\min(m,n)$,
2. $r$ is the codimension of the solution set.

Can you conclude?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm still kinda confused :(
From what i understand n-r is the dimension of the solution set, but I'm still not sure where to go from there

Comment: Your interpretation is correct . To obtain an answer, plug in the inequalities $r\le m$ and $r\le n$. What can you deduce for $n-r$?

Comment: So for  r $\leqslant$ m, I get n-r $\leqslant$ n-m and for r $\leqslant$ n, I get n-r $\leqslant$ n-n=0
So would a) be the answer? And does that mean that the number of equation has to greater or equal to the number of unknowns? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: With $\color{red}{\mathbf -}r$, you have to reverse the inequalities. Also, note a dimension can't be negative.